# ESD Diode - clamping voltage

Tags: capacitor, can, esd, power-dissipation, diode-clamp

I'm trying to replace an existing ESD diode(PESD1CAN) in my application CAN circuitry due to some reasons, I've found an alternative ESD diode(RSB27C2), but compared to the diode that I already have in my circuit, it's not that great clamping negative voltages as depicted in the below picture.THe above graph is for the new diode that I'm considering and the below one is for the already existing diode in my circuit. I'm assuming that the negative scale is not shown but the green curves denote the clamped voltage during a negative ESD pulse and the horizontal axis is the timescale : 50ns per division, so I see that for about 100ns the clamped voltage would be about -75V , whereas my existing diode is better at clamping it to -45V.
[image]

What I'm interested in knowing is how this would affect the components on the line where the voltage is being clamped, 
[image]
In my understanding, the negative clamped voltage would appear at CANL and Gnd, and how this extra negative voltage for a very short time(100ns) would impact C418, R413, R414, C410 and the common mode choke L400

Comment: You chopped off the timescale on the graph

Comment: This seems to be a popular question.  Related recent one ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1099318?noredirect=1

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Related question ,but not the same question.

Comment: What does the layout look like? parasitic inductance can drastically reduce the effectiveness of the diodes.

Comment: CAN you not compare max. Specs against your results. 75V exceeds input.

Comment: Yeah , but would the capacitors take the voltage and thus at the input it would be much lesser ? Also the voltage is only for a very short duration, 100ns

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you need such a diode? The transceivers are typically rated up to 6kV contact discharge. TJA1042 is rated at 8kV which is the toughest requirement by IEC 61000-4-2. If you need tougher yet there's the new MCP2561 with 14kV, almost twice the double of the toughest ESD requirement. But this still isn't enough for you? You actually need 23kV provided by PESD1CAN? For... a device designed for cats, or...? Or are you using these instead of TVS?

Comment: Usually automative OEMs have a list of qualified parts for their CAN circuitry, that's how PESD1CAN was chosen from the list. Also in the application note of TJA1042T , they have suggested to use PESD1CAN

Comment: But what you actually seem to want are TVS diodes (for example SM15T) to protect about various voltage spikes. Since 23kV doesn't make much sense with the "human body model".

Comment: PESD1CAN is also a Voltage suppressor